# check if data exist in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if data already exists in firebase database

this is my code to show  data  from firebase database  :

```
    databaseCars.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            carsList.clear();

            for(DataSnapshot carSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Cars cars = carSnapshot.getValue(Cars.class);
                carsList.add(cars);
            }

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new CarsList(listView_Car.this,carsList);
            listViewCars.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, what's the error/problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding

```
if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(dataToAdd)) {
    // data exist 
}
```

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#haschild